# C# FaceBook error, Error Message: next is not owned by the application

Tags: c#, facebook

This is a one page site I'm using to understand FB. I'm trying to get FB Connect to work.

I've tried several tutorials, two different domains, and tweaked the app settings on FB. All I seem to be able to get is the above error message.

I've read several answers on this site but my FB app setting don't match the any of the answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use should use Facebook rest api.And make sure that you have registered your website at facebook to connect, and you should have ApplicationKey and SecretKey.

and to connect facebook

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="window.location.reload()"></fb:login-button>
```

Then for access permission
 Collapse | Copy Code

```
<fb:prompt-permission perms="email"> allow mail  permission</fb:prompt-permission>
```

Add reference facebook api in your project.

```
ConnectSession connectSession = new ConnectSession
    (ConnectAuthentication.ApiKey,ConnectAuthentication.SecretKey);    
if(connectSession.IsConnected==true)//you sucessfully connected
```